# extract bit in Ruby Integers

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

I need to get the n-th bit of an Integer, either signed or unsigned, in Ruby.

```
x = 123 # that is 1111011
n = 2   # bit 2 is ...0
```

The following piece of code doesn't work in the general case:

```
x.to_s(2)[-(n+1)] #0 good! but...
```

because of negative numbers not represented as 2-complement:

```
-123.to_s(2) # "-1111011"
```

So how to proceed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
x = 123 # that is 1111011
n = 2   # bit 2 is ...0

x[n]    # => 0

-123[2] # => 1
```

Comment: the results 1 and 0 are inversed. I tried to edit your post without success

Comment: @JCLL: Thanks! That's one case where cut&paste would actually have *prevented* a bug :-)

Comment: Heh, yet another cool Ruby operator: [] on Fixnum, somehow both plain as day in the docs yet buried out of sight at the same time.

Comment: Is there a way to _set_ the bit at that index, instead of just get? e.g. `a=2; a[0] = 1; a #=>3` ?

Comment: @Mirror318: No. `Integer`s are immutable.

Answer (score 6):

```
def f x, bit
  (x & 1 << bit) > 0 ? 1 : 0
end
```

Comment: And if you just want a true/false result you can leave out the `? 1 : 0`

Answer (score 3):

You could try the  [Bindata lib](http://bindata.rubyforge.org/).

There is a function to represent an integer's binary representation as a string, and after that, you can do what you like with it.